# Javascript - Trying to delay iterating through for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've tried finding my answers in other posts and can find bits and pieces, but not a complete answer. So, sorry if this is a duplicate question - best I can tell, it's not.

I'm trying to accomplish three things:

1. Delay iterating through a for loop for one second between itmes
2. Revert the previous item to its original state before moving on to the next item
3. Start the loop all over again after the last item

I've accomplished the first, but can't figure how to accomplish the next two.

Here's a watered-down code sample:

HTML:

```
<p>First paragraph.</p>
<p>Second paragraph.</p>
<p>Third paragraph.</p>
<p>Fourth paragraph.</p>
<p>Fifth paragraph.</p>
<p>Sixth paragraph.</p>
<p>Seventh paragraph.</p>
<p>Eighth paragraph.</p>
<p>Nineth paragraph.</p>
<p>Tenth paragraph.</p>
```

CSS:

```
p.red {color: red;}
```

JS:

```
function addRed() {
    var spans = $('p'),
        count = spans.length,
        delay = 1000;
    for(var i = 0; i <= count; i++) {
        (timer(i, spans, delay));
    } 
}

function timer(a, b, c) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(b[a]).toggleClass('red');
  }, c * a);
} (0);

addRed();
```

I'd like for the first `<p>` in this example to turn red, wait for one second, then turn the second `<p>` red and revert the first back to its original state. Then, once the cycle has completed (iterated through the entire list of `<p>`s), start again at the top. I.e.; a repeating loop.

Sorry if this is asking three separate questions. It's easier and makes more sense to just group them all together.

Here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Currell/wb0o99cq/1/).

As a final note, I'm not tied to any of this code. If needed, I'm open to changing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in a much more concise manner.

```js
(function addRed(elems, i, delay) {
    elems.eq(i).addClass("red");
    setTimeout(function() {
        elems.eq(i).removeClass("red");
        addRed(elems, ++i % elems.length, delay);
    }, delay);
})($("p"), 0, 1000);
```

```css
p.red {color: red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>First paragraph.</p>
<p>Second paragraph.</p>
<p>Third paragraph.</p>
<p>Fourth paragraph.</p>
<p>Fifth paragraph.</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. For *point #2*, simply remove the class `red` from all `p` elements and then add to the current
2. For *point #3*, use [**index()**](http://api.jquery.com/index/) to check if this is the last timeout and start over again after one second

```js
function addRed() {
  var spans = $('p'),
    count = spans.length,
    delay = 1000;
  for (var i = 0; i <= count; i++) {
    (timer(i, spans, delay));
  }
}

function timer(a, b, c) {
  setTimeout(function() {

    $('p').removeClass('red');
    $(b[a]).addClass('red');

    var currentIndex = $(b[a]).index();
    if (currentIndex == $('p').length) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        addRed();
      }, 1000);
    }
  }, c * a);
}(0);

addRed();
```

```css
p.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>First paragraph.</p>
<p>Second paragraph.</p>
<p>Third paragraph.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an interval instead of timeout like

```js
var interval;

function addRed() {

  var $ps = $('p'),
    i = -1,
    count = $ps.length;;

  interval = setInterval(function() {
    $ps.eq(i).removeClass('red');
    i = ++i < count ? i : 0;
    $ps.eq(i).addClass('red');
  }, 500)
}


addRed();
```

```css
p.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>First paragraph.</p>
<p>Second paragraph.</p>
<p>Third paragraph.</p>
<p>Fourth paragraph.</p>
<p>Fifth paragraph.</p>
<p>Sixth paragraph.</p>
<p>Seventh paragraph.</p>
<p>Eighth paragraph.</p>
<p>Nineth paragraph.</p>
<p>Tenth paragraph.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close.

I added 2 conditionals.  One to your setTimeout function to satisfy condition 2, and one to your for loop to satisfy condition 3.

Here is the updated code

```
function addRed() {
  var spans = $('p'),
    count = spans.length,
    delay = 1000;
  for(var i = 0; i <= count; i++) {
    (timer(i, spans, delay));
    if (i === count) {
      i = 0; 
    }
  } 
}

function timer(a, b, c) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (a > 0) {
      $(b[a-1]).toggleClass('red');
    }
    $(b[a]).toggleClass('red');
  }, c * a);
} (0);

addRed();
```